# preserving source ip in kubernetes external traffic policy cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have one master and three worker nodes in my k8s setup which uses externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster and type: NodePort  so that external packet coming on master node can be forward to destination pod irrespective of node. But in this case, I loose source IP due to SNAT. Is there a way to preserve the source IP till the packet reaches to its destination pod. I do not want to use load balancer in my setup.  Is there any option in kube-proxy to achieve this? Or any other workaround?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak this is not an issue. This is a std behavior irrespective of ks8 version. Which is a big hurdle to achieve my objective. Hence, looking for a workaround in such situation

Comment: So please provide your yaml files to the question.